# Element of string at specified index

Tags: code-golf, string

Given a string `s` and a non-negative number `n` less than the length of `s`, output the character at the `n`-th position of `s`.

0-indexing and 1-indexing are allowed. For 1-indexing, `n` will be positive and less than or equal to the length of `s`.

`s` will consist of printable characters only.

Any reasonable input/output is permitted. [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.

Testcases (0-indexing):

```
n s        output
0 "abcde"  a
1 "abcde"  b
2 "a != b" !
3 "+-*/"   /
4 "314159" 5
```

Testcases (1-indexing):

```
n s        output
1 "abcde"  a
2 "abcde"  b
3 "a != b" !
4 "+-*/"   /
5 "314159" 5
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: I downvoted this because it's​ not really a programming or golfing challenge; all that's essentially being asked here is which language has the shortest built-in​ for the job.

Comment: @Shaggy Same for many other simple challenges like adding two numbers, testing if a number is prime or printing "Hello, World!". While these are boring in many languages that can do them out of the box, they can be interesting challenges for more primitive languages that have to roll their own implementation. Plus, anything more complicated is usually too much to ask of those languages, so it's nice to have an outlet for them. If trivial challenges bore you, try doing them in a nontrivial language.

Answer (score 9):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 1 byte

```
)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@6/5/796SEZmsQIQJSoUlxRl5qWrcxkDAA)

Well, hard to make it much simpler. `)` indexes the first input, using the second input value. This is 1-indexed.

Answer (score 8):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 5 bytes

```
I&IO@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#JcshEsNQDAPRs5QE25ZsSyw0qPc/zW9mSvahPc/1fO9zPkhm@9@aRstrFMSpISDUuqMkpjfHsLGd0arw0uQ7IlY5jClNhewXBahqsDI3Zn8)

As usual it's much shorter if we avoid Ordinal mode and use an abysmal input format. Here, the first [character's code point is used as the integer input](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-the-form-of-byte-values). The remainder of the input is the string. The index is 1-based.

#### Explanation

```
I   Read a character and push its code point.
&I  Read that many more characters and push them.
O   Output the last one we read.
@   Terminate the program.
```

Comment: `abysmal` - I thought you made it xD

Comment: @StephenS You mean I proposed this I/O format on meta? Yeah, I did, but mostly for languages that would have to implement their own decimal integer parser/renderer each time they compete in a challenge with numerical I/O, so they would likely just skip those entirely. But it has the unfortunate side effect that in some languages which *can* read and write decimal quite easily it's still shorter to use code points instead.

Answer (score 7):

## Python, 15 bytes

```py
str.__getitem__
```

or

```py
lambda s,i:s[i]
```

Both take 2 arguments: the string and the index. 0-indexed.

Comment: I'm surprised both methods have the same length.

Answer (score 6):

### Haskell, 4 bytes

```
(!!)
```

0-based indexing. Usage example: `(!!) "Hello" 1`-> `'e'`.

Answer (score 5):

## Octave, 10 bytes

```
@(s,n)s(n)
```

Takes a string `s`, and a number `n` as input, and returns the `n`th character of `s`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>28</s> <s>20</s> 19 bytes

*Saved 8 bytes thanks to @MartinEnder by not using balancing groups*

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @mbomb007 by using `^.+` instead of `^\d+`*

```
^.+
$*
+`1¶.
¶
!1`.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#U9UITrD@H6enzaWixaWdYHhomx7XoW1cioYJev//G1gnJiWnpHIZQmkj60QFRVuFJC5ja21dLX0uE2tjQxNDU0sA)

The program is 0-indexed.

Comment: Change `\d` to `.` to save a byte.

Comment: @mbomb007 Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 byte

0-indexed.

```
è
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@394xf//JlzGhiaGppYA)

Answer (score 3):

### [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 3 bytes

```
{=}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#M1BQSkxKTklV4jKEs4yALAVFW4UkJS5jBSVtXS19JS4TBSVjQxNDU0slrlgj/eq6/9W2tf/rCmr1/wMA)

`=` is the built-in for list/string indexing.

Answer (score 3):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 10 bytes

```
/@!O?]&
 I
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@6/voOhvH6vGpeD5/7@xoYmhqSWXCQA)

Expects the string on the first line and the 0-based index on the second line.

#### Explanation

Despite its wealth of built-ins, string indexing doesn't exist in Alice. The reason is that it requires both an integer and a string parameter, and all commands in Alice are strictly integers to integers or strings to strings.

In general, the main way to perform any operations on strings that require or result in integers is to store the string on the tape in Ordinal mode, which you can then manipulate with integers in Cardinal mode.

```
/    Reflect to SE. Switch to Ordinal. While in Ordinal mode, the IP bounces
     diagonally up and down through the program.
I    Read one line from STDIN and push it.
!    Store the string on the tape. This writes the character codes into consecutive
     tape cells starting at the tape head. (It also writes a -1 at the end as a
     terminator, but the tape is initialised to -1s anyway).

     The next few commands are junk that luckily doesn't affect the program:

?      Load the string from the tape and push it to the stack again.
&      Fold the next command over this string. That is, for each character
       in the string, push that character, then execute the command.
?      So we're folding "load" over the string itself. So if the string is "abc"
       we'll end up with "a" "abc" "b" "abc" "c" "abc" on the stack.
!      Store the top copy of "abc" on the tape (does nothing, because it's
       already there).

     Now the relevant part of the program continues.

I    Read another line from STDIN, i.e. the string representation of the index.
/    Reflect to W. Switch to Cardinal. The IP wraps to the last column.
&    Implicitly convert the string to the integer value it represents and
     repeat the next command that many times.
]    Move the tape head right that many cells. Note that Ordinal and Cardinal
     mode have separate tape heads, but they are initialised to the same cell.
?    Load the value from that cell, which is the code point of the character
     at the given index.
O    Print the corresponding character.
!    This discards or converts some of the strings on the stack and writes some
     value back to the tape, but it's irrelevant.
@    Terminate the program.
```

Comment: "Despite its wealth of built-ins, string indexing doesn't exist in Alice." >_>

Comment: @LeakyNun If you think that's bad, there's also no built-in to get a string's length. ;)

Answer (score 3):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), <s>40</s> 37 bytes

```
q(L,N,A):-nth0(N,L,X),char_code(A,X).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/prolog-swi#@1@o4aPjp@OoaaWbV5JhoOGn46MToamTnJFYFJ@cn5Kq4Qjk6v3/X6iRYGxoYmhqmaBjAhIBAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 8 bytes

```
t@poIA//
```

This solution is 1-indexed. The input should consist of a number first, then a separator (that is not a digit or a `.`) and then the string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cubix#@1/iUJDv6aiv//@/iUJiUnJKahoA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
ị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9wd/f///9N/itp62rpKwEA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 2 bytes

```
∋₎
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@/@oo/tRU9///9FKxoYmhqaWSjomsf@jAA)

#### Explanation

`∋` unifies its output with an element of the Input. With `₎` as subscript, it will unify its output with the `I`th element of `S`, with `[S,I]` as input.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 bytes

```
gV
```

This solution is 0-indexed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@58e9v@/UmJSckpqmpKOggkA)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
s=>n=>s[n]
```

Uses 0-based indexing.

*-1 byte thanks to @Leaky Nun*

```js
f=
s=>n=>s[n]
console.log(f("abcde")(0));
console.log(f("abcde")(1));
console.log(f("a != b")(2));
console.log(f("+-*/")(3));
console.log(f("314159")(4));
```

Comment: you can use currying `s=>i=>s[i]` to save a byte

Comment: Every time I see answers like this it annoys me because I know the C# version is always one byte longer for the semi colon on the end. And that is indeed the case here

Answer (score 2):

## [Carrot](https://github.com/kritixilithos/Carrot/), 16 bytes

```
$^//.{#}/S1//.$/
```

[Try it online!](http://kritixilithos.github.io/Carrot/)

The input format is as such:

```
string
index
```

And the program is 1-indexed.

#### Explanation

Carrot has several global variables, one for each type: string, float and array (others to be implemented soon). The program starts in string-mode, where all the operators will affect the global string variable. And I call these variables the "stack".

(Example input: `abcdef\n3`)

```
$                          Get the first line of the input and set the stack-string to this value
^                          Exit caret-mode
                           stack-string = "abcdef"
/                          Operator (behaves differently depending on the argument)
 /.{#}/                     And the argument to this operator is a regex, so this program gets the matches of this regex into the stack-array
  .                          Any character
   {#}                       Pops a line from the input. So now this evaluates to # of any character where # is the second line of the input (in this case, 3)
                           stack-array = ["abc"]
                           And now we just need to get the last character in this string, but first
S1                         Join the array on the number 1 and set this to the stack-string. Because the array only contains one element, the number 1 does not appear in the stack-string.
                           stack-string = "abc"
/                          Operator; because the argument is a regex, this retrieves the matches of the regex:
 /.$/                       Get the last character in the string
                           stack-array = ["c"]
```

Now this returns a one element array containing a string of length one, but it is shown as a string in the website.

If we really wanted to give the result as a string, we could easily do `S","` at the end, but it doesn't matter because the output still looks the same on the interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 13 + 1 = 14 bytes

+1 for `-v` flag to take input

```
:?!\i~1-
io;\
```

*Thanks to [@steenbergh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44874) for notifying me about the `-v` flag and saving me 3 bytes!*

Input the index with the command line argument `-v [index]` (0-indexed) and input the string through stdin.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#@29lrxiTWWeoy5WZbx3z/7@BoZGxiamZuUUFiPVft0zBEgA)

#### Explanation

The stack starts with the index on top.
`:` duplicates it.
`?` ignores the next character if the index is 0. (Popping it off the stack)
If it is zero, `\` reflects the direction to go down. Then, it is reflected to the right with the next `\`. It wraps around and executes `i`nput a character, `o`utput it and `;` halts execution.
If not, `!` skips the next instruction, so it doesn't go down.
`i~` inputs a character and then immediately discards it.
`1` pushes 1.
`-` subtractes `1` from the index, so one character in the input is consumed and the index is decremented. The program loops around back to the `:`.

Comment: There is the `-v <x>` command line parameter, which initialises the stack to hold `<x>` on program start. [Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#@69QxlVml1lnqGtlr8iVyZXPZf3/v4GhkbGJqZm5RQWI9V@3TMESAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [S.I.L.O.S](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), 43 bytes

```
loadLine
readIO
a=256+i
a=get a
printChar a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/silos#@5@Tn5jik5mXylWUmpji6c@VaGtkaqadCaTTU0sUErkKijLzSpwzEosUEv///1@QX5JYkv/fCAA)

Simple enough.

Comment: SILOS is back \o/

Comment: Yeah,  I'm trying to answer as many callenges as possible, including the windows loading screen one. I like the point it's at in terms of graphical output, and libraries, but I still would like to develope a compression scheme to try and get it competitive. Essentially the int[] it compiles to can be generated through reading a byte stream. @LeakyNun

Answer (score 2):

## [BF](https://esolangs.org/wiki/brainfuck), 9 bytes

```bash
,[->,<]>.
```

The index is taken via the character code of a char (like the Alice submission). Following that, we have the string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#LcxLCoAgFEDRuat4ONYMmoYbqQZ@XiTFU0yh3Rt9xudy0W0RJCHw@eoHY53HlYOGLlCqhTF8nDcxSS3GRXftRRc9MhVTUSVEWbKhM4UD86lsNoHW6vYvgvE/tRs)

The TIO link uses a Bash wrapper and the input can be changed in the header file (the reason for the wrapper is so that we can see the bytes).

Comment: Legit TIO hacking :p

Comment: @LeakyNun I used the [wrapper for BF](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/blob/master/wrappers/brainfuck).

Comment: I did say it is legit.

Comment: Is there a way to do input to other TIO languages like that? Like SMBF?

Comment: @mbomb007 You should be able to do that for other languages by using their wrappers. Here's the wrapper for [SMBF](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/blob/master/wrappers/smbf)

Comment: Is there a way to put unprintables in the source code using a method like that. Like `.code` instead of `.input`?

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 3

```
nth
```

:P What can you do when there is a [built-in](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/nth) for this? This works on lists, vectors, strings and sequences. It is either O(1) or O(n), depending on the used datatype.

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 32 bytes

```
@set/ps=
@call echo(%%s:~%1,1%%
```

Reads `s` from STDIN and takes `n` as a command-line parameter.

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), <s>7</s> 4 bytes

```
~1/=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/golfscript#@19nqG/7/7@xgpK2rpa@EgA)

I suck in GolfScript, so I value [Martin Ender](/u/8478)'s help.

Comment: There's no need for the `[`.

Comment: But in general if you want characters from strings, you just split the string first instead of converting the code point back: `~1/=`

Comment: @MartinEnder And that's how you beat Alice up...

Answer (score 1):

## [Turtlèd](https://github.com/Destructible-Watermelon/Turtl-d), 9 bytes

```
!?:[*l+].
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/turtled#@69obxWtlaMdq/f/P5zJZQAA)

### explanation:

First off, Turtlèd is grid based, with a turtle thing. There are grid cells the turtle can move left, up, down, and right on, and can write things on the grid cells.

```
[the first grid cell the turtle starts on is marked with a *]
!         input the string into the string variable

 ?        input the number into the number variable

  :       this command takes the number variable and moves right that many.
          hence this moves right by the amount inputted

   [*  ]  this is an `until` loop. the * there means that `until` the turtle ends the loop
          on a grid cell with * written on it (that is, the first cell), it will execute
          the code inside again and again

     l+   the code inside the while loop. the `l` moves the turtle left, and the +
          increments the string pointer. the string pointer is used with the string var;
          when you want to write something from the string, you use `.`, which writes
          the pointed char. the pointed char is the n-th character of the string, n being
          the value of the string pointer. this code will execute until the l moves
          the turtle back on to the origin cell. since we moved right by the number
          inputted, this will increase the string pointer (which starts at 1)
          by the amount inputted.

       .  write the pointed char, which was dealt with in the previous comment.
          if 0 is inputted, turtle stayed on the origin square, and executed none
          of the loop, and turtle writes the first char of string input.
          if 1 is inputted, turtle moved one right, moved one left and incremented
          string pointer once, which means the second char is written. and so on.


          [the char of input has been written over the origin square]
          [implicitly the grid is outputted, which has spaces and blank lines taken out]
          [this is the requested char outputted, plus an unavoidable trailing newline
          due to how I made the interpreter. sue me]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 31 bytes

```
:
/^1/{s:1 .: :;b}
s: (.).*:\1:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/sed#@2/FpR9nqF9dbGWooGelYGWdVMtVbKWgoaepp2UVY2j1/79CYlJySiqXIYwGMhQUbRWSgCxDBW1dLX0Qw1DB2NDE0NTyX35BSWZ@XvF/3SIA)

Input: index and the string, separated by one space. Index in unary, but zero-based.

Answer (score 1):

## Axiom, 1 byte

```
.
```

1-Indexing... string.index is the value of string at index 
some test

```
(5) -> "123".6
   >> Error detected within library code:
   index out of range
    protected-symbol-warn called with (NIL)

(5) -> "123".0
   >> Error detected within library code:
   index out of range
protected-symbol-warn called with (NIL)

(5) -> ["123".i  for i in 1..3]
   (5)  [1,2,3]
                                                     Type: List Character
```

Where you see Axiom warn for index out of space too

Comment: Snippets are not allowed. Only functions/full programs are allowed.

Comment: @LeakyNun I can not see it as operator? (and so one function)

Comment: A function is which you can give a name to. Would `f=.` make sense?

Comment: @LeakyNun that operator has already a name '.' Why I have to call in a different way?

Comment: @RosLuP to be a valid answer in a challenge with I/O, you have to have a program that reads input, or a function that gets passed input as parameters and returns output. I don't know axiom, but see my JavaScript answer - it will probably look similar.

Comment: @StephenS We're accepting the names of built-in functions as function submissions, so I don't see why we shouldn't accept the names of built-in operators (which *are* functions, just usually with different syntax).

Comment: @MartinEnder, I agree with that reasoning, but where should the line be drawn? Should operators that have added syntactic sugar be allowed as well? Python's `a[b]` is just syntactic sugar for `str.__getitem__(a,b)`, for example; if `.` is a valid solution here, should `[]` be a valid solution in Python and other similar languages? I'm probably overlooking some obvious difference between the two cases, but none comes to mind immediately.

Comment: @JulianWolf It might be good to settle this debate on meta. (I don't have the time to write up a post right now though.)

Comment: I think we've already discussed a lot of related questions on Meta (although I haven't found one that addresses this situation specifically), and IIRC a function submission has to be a function `value`. So in Haskell, for example, `+` isn't a valid solution to "add 2 numbers", but `(+)` is.

Comment: @ais523 [Found it.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7206/8478) You're essentially right.

Answer (score 1):

## [Dyvil](https://github.com/dyvil/dyvil), 4 Bytes

```
_[_]
```

Creates an anonymous function that takes a `String` and an `int` and returns a `char`.

Usage:

```
let f: (String, int) -> char = _[_]
print f("abc", 1) // b
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 3 bytes

```
a@b
```

This is 0-based. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#@5/okPT///@Kyqr/hgA)

Answer (score 1):

### QBasic 4.5, 24 bytes

```
INPUT a$,b:?MID$(a$,b,1)
```

Pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

## Vim, 8 bytes

```
DJ@"|xVp
```

Since V is backwards compatible, you can [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@@/i5aBUUxFW8P@/IZejk7OLoxMA)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 18 bytes

```
#~StringTake~{#2}&
```

Basic solution, but unfortunately the function name is quite long.

Answer (score 1):

### C#, 11 bytes

```
s=>n=>s[n];
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 28 bytes

```
print(input()[int(input())])
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>18</s> <s>17</s> 12 bytes

```
s->s::charAt
```

-5 bytes saved thanks to *@Jakob*.

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##lYw9b8IwEIb3/IqDKaHENIUOfEVCSEgdOjFWHS6OoU4d27IvSAjx21NTaOZ0urv3veep8ISpsUJX5Xcra2scQRUy1pBU7NBoTtJotnssy4gr9B7eUepLBGCbQkkOnpDCOBlZQh2qeE9O6uPHJ2ByewP4E6zuzbi73zSJo3Dj7Rc65CRcngOHdevT3C8WPKQbam@G5a9nf/YkamYaYjaISOmYM7RWneMhFrwUw@RxPifJf5GsFwKDNRQd89KHeUpHk46Y9iGm2Sx7nXfM7M5co2v7Aw)

## Java 7, 43 bytes

```
char c(String s,int n){return s.charAt(n);}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#jcyxDoIwFIXhnac4MrWKKIKDIQ4@gBOjcSiFaBMopL2YGMKzY4nM6Hy@/8hKWItr7wGWBCmJUT6FgWQZGaUfsIHSBM17U1JnNGw47RdimqfDCLRdXrlqjl@NKlALpef8dofg0zmQvS2Vddh0FLZuokozyXyRy6L0A@w5T/9g0Q@G1Rm5c4dlt9mud07FyyqOkuh4ci75usEbxg8)

Both 0-indexed.

Comment: Can you use currying i.e. `s->n->...` to save a byte? And does Java not have indexers i.e. `s[n]`?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Yes, and no. Was indeed just trying to write the currying answer in TryItOnline. But since I've barely used Java 8, I'm a bit unsure how to go about it. But you're indeed right that currying saves a byte, was about to change it. As the `s[n]`. String is an Object, so you can do things like `s.equals(...)` and `s.charAt(...)` to `s.toCharArray()`. With an array you are able to do `[n]`, like `int a=new int[]{1,2,3,4}; int result = a[0]; // <- a[0] = 1`

Comment: In C# you'd do `Func<string, Func<int, char>>` so something similar I assume.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder You're indeed right, should have a working TIO now.

Comment: Since you're already currying, save another 5 bytes with a method reference: `s->s::charAt`.

Comment: @Jakob Could you perhaps create a TIO. I'm tbh not entirely sure how I can combine currying and a method reference at the same time.. I only use Java 8 for golfing, and Java 7 kind of methods in day-to-day work.

Comment: Sure! It's a simple change: [TIO](https://tio.run/##lYw9b8IwEIb3/IqDKaHENIUOfEVCSEgdOjFWHS6OoU4d27IvSAjx21NTaOZ0urv3veep8ISpsUJX5Xcra2scQRUy1pBU7NBoTtJotnssy4gr9B7eUepLBGCbQkkOnpDCOBlZQh2qeE9O6uPHJ2ByewP4E6zuzbi73zSJo3Dj7Rc65CRcngOHdevT3C8WPKQbam@G5a9nf/YkamYaYjaISOmYM7RWneMhFrwUw@RxPifJf5GsFwKDNRQd89KHeUpHk46Y9iGm2Sx7nXfM7M5co2v7Aw)

Comment: The method reference essentially extracts the `charAt` method from `String` `s`. `s::charAt` has the same type as your inner lambda: `Function<Integer, Character>`.

Answer (score 1):

### [k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_(programming_language)) ([kona](https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona)), 0 bytes (noncompeting); 1 byte

In K, list access (as function application) is implicit. As such, we can do

```
q)"abcdef"0 
"a"
```

But that's not really in the spirit of things, so we'll make the application of 0 on "abcdef" explicit for 1 byte:

```
q)"abcdef"@0
"a"
```

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 14 bytes

```
Prompt Str0,N
sub(Str0,N,1
```

Returns the Nth 1-indexed character of the string.

Noncompeting 10 bytes:

```
Prompt N
sub(Ans,N,1
```

run with: `"string":prgmNAME` then input the number. I can't see the upvote/downvote ratio of [this meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5415/44694) on whether different input types are allowed, and it doesn't say in the tag-wiki, so I'm assuming they aren't.

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), 17 bytes

...because why not?

```
,[,>+<-]>[<,>-],.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brainfuck#@68TrWOnbaMbaxdto2OnG6uj9/@/oaEhY6KCoq1CEgA)

Uses 0-indexing, takes number in unary, `n` separated from `s` by .

[This](https://tio.run/nexus/brainfuck#@68TrWOnbaMLB7F20TY6drqxOnr//xsaGnIlKijaKiQBAA) separates `n` from `s` with a newline.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 9 bytes

```
proc &:[]
```

How Ruby handles operator overloading is `:+`, `:-`, `:*`, `:[]`, etc. are defined as methods, so `1+2` is essentially `1.+(2)`. `:[]` is the symbol for the subscripting "operator", which when converted to a `proc` calls the `:[]` method with the first as a receiver and the second as an argument. E.g., `(proc &:[]).call("asd",0) == "asd".[](0) == "asd"[0]`

Answer (score 1):

## [J-uby](http://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 3 bytes

```rb
:[]
```

`[]` is the subscripting operator. Example run:

```rb
irb(main):001:0> f = :[]
irb(main):002:0> f.call("string", 2)
=> "r"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Integral](https://github.com/nph278/integral), 2 Bytes

Integral doesn't have an `a[n]` built-in. Unfortunately it does have some slicing built-ins, which makes a 2-byter possible...

```
rn
```

[Try it!](https://nph278.github.io/integral/?code=cm4&input=%22abcde%22%0A0%0A%0A%22abcde%22%0A1%0A%0A%22a%20%21%3D%20b%22%0A2%0A%0A%22+-*/%22%0A3%0A%0A%22314159%22%0A4)

### Explanation

```
r   Last b
 n  Head
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 3 bytes

```
nth
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqVQnFpYmpqXnFqsUFCUWlJSWVCUmVeikJ1alJeao2DNxWWooJSYlJySqvQ/ryTjv95/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
i
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiaSIsIiIsIjAsIFwiYWJjZGVcIlxuMywgXCJhYmNkZVwiIl0=)

Can't get much simpler than this.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 1 byte

```
i
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWCzOXFCclF0N5C1YacSklJiWnpCpBBAA)

Built-in.

Answer (score 0):

### C, 18 Bytes

```
#define f(s,n)s[n]
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@6@ckpqWmZeqkKZRrJOnWRydF/s/NzEzT0OTq5qLs6AoM68kTUNJNVlJB6hCKVFB0VYhSUnHSFPTmqv2PwA)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 22 Bytes

```php
<?=$argv[1][$argv[2]];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#@29jb6uSWJReFm0YGw1hGMXGWv///7@4pCgzL10BQv03NAQA)

Answer (score 0):

## Swift - 53 bytes

```swift
func f(a:String,i:Int){print(Array(a.characters)[i])}
```

A function `f` that can be used as `f(a: "abcdef",i: 3)`. It is 0-indexed.

**[Check it out!](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5917088585c3fe781a037d65)**

Answer (score 0):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 8 bytes

```
?_s;,:,1
```

Explanation:

```
?     PRINT
_s    Substring(in$, start, length)
  ;   Reads a string from the cmd line as in$
  ,:  Reads an int from the command line as start
  ,1  One character
      Statement delimeter | is auto-added at EOF.
```

This is 1-based. It uses QBIC's new ability to inline `;` and `:`. Previously, to get `s` and `n`, you needed to do this:

```
;:?_sA,a,1
```

That would create the assignment of a cmd line arg to `A$` and `a` resp. Now we can skip assignment: the interpreter extracts the assignment and moves those to the top of the script.

Answer (score 0):

## [Fireball](https://github.com/okx-code/Fireball), 3 bytes

1-indexed.

```
╡1╞
```

Explanation:

```
╡         Get the first n characters of the input
 1╞       Get the last character of the that
```

Alternatively, for 4 bytes:

```
╡r↔♥
```

Explanation:

```
╡      Get the first n characters of the input
 r     Reverse
  ↔♥   Get the first character
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 18 bytes

```
{substr $^a,$^b,1}
```

I'm a little surprised it can't be done shorter.  By me, anyway.

Comment: could you remove the space before the first `$`? Not too familiar with Perl

Comment: Nope.  Perl 6 requires whitespace in many places that Perl 5 doesn't.

Comment: that seems very un-Perl-like if that's a thing

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom,61 bytes

```
f(s:String,n:PI):Union(Character,Complex INT)==(n>#s=>%i;s.n)
```

1-Indexing; it return the required char or it return the  %i=sqrt(-1) for error if n> lenght(s)
Some test

```
(4) -> [f("123",i) for i in 1..10]
   (4)  [1,2,3,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i]
                              Type: List Union(Character,Complex Integer)
(5) -> f("123", 0)
   Conversion failed in the compiled user function f .
   Cannot convert from type Integer to PositiveInteger for value
   0
```

instead of doing less (few characters) instead of do more (more cicle) instead to do fast... to do the right

Answer (score 0):

## LLVM IR, 72 bytes

```
define i8*@a(i8*,i64){
entry:%2=getelementptr i8,i8*%0,i64%1
ret i8*%2
}
```

Takes a `(string, index)` (0-indexed) as argument, where `string` is a c-string. Returns an `i8*` (`char*`) which points to the desired char. I can't directly move the `getelementptr` with the `ret` instruction as `%0` and `%1` are function-local and therefore need their own instruction

[Try it online!](https://vihan.org/p/tio/?l=llvm&p=S0lNy8xLVci00HJI1ACSOplmJprVXKl5JUWVVqpGtumpJak5qblAfkFJEVCZDlCNqgFIlYKqIVdRaglIq6oRV@1/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell, 18 Bytes

```
param($s,$i)$s[$i]
```

indexes into param 1 (`$s`) using param 2 (`$i`)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 15 bytes

```perl6
{$^s.comb[$^n]}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#RY9bboMwEEX/ZxU3FqogGChNUqnhoS6if4FIPFwpEhgUk6oVIotp15E1ZQmpQXn8eDw@c0fHByXw9eoWAdU/eCqaUiC69MZWuUVT5xtjK9PhotF7J1SHCNVOCmVabp21656Aeq08XQAjlLHmZlLa1vRwPv2y8@kPx/vNCNU0EjoblsZz65oT360oOlGOTKMEaayJF@jDHrdyHMfkVO6zNNBBq39oq4DaKpOwJ8WAPpv91daJtY7kieLJLWdhlN4pjD81JVcWx41xsF4O6JXbin01MBouz2BZXpSCARn5jyanF91gFiFnmNECzHbmngbwaAm28Jf@6o1hRf8)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{ # bare block lambda with placeholder parameters ｢$n｣ and ｢$s｣

  $^s      # declare second parameter
  .comb\   # split it into graphemes
  [ $^n ]  # get the value indexed by the first parameter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy 11 bytes

```
{s,n->s[n]}
```

0-indexed.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 3 bytes

```
§ＳＮ
```

## Explanation

```
§     At index
 Ｓ   Input string
   Ｎ Input number
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/charcoal#@39o@fs9m9/vWff/f7RSYlJySqqSjoJB7H/dTCS@YSyIo6Boq5AE5BmBeNq6WvpAtjGIbWxoYmhqCeSZAPXl/0/8n/Rf8b/@f1MA)

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 1 byte

`⌷` (Index) or `⊃` (Pick)

[Try them online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#@///v@Gjnu3qiUnJKanqXEZIbGMwW0HRViFJncsExNHW1dJX5zIFMY0NTQxNLdW5DB91NSM0I9jGYDZcM5AD0wxkQjUDAA)

They only differ for higher rank arrays and nested arrays:

`2⌷A` will choose the second element or second row, leaving any nesting
`2⊃A` will pick the second element, and attempt to remove one level of nesting

`2 3⌷A` will choose the element at row 2 column 3
`2 3⊃A` will pick the third element of the second element

`(⊂2 3)⌷A` will choose the second and third elements or rows
`(⊂2 3)⊃A` will pick the element at row 2 column 3

Answer (score 0):

## [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip), 114 bytes

```
*Z
,x.z.
`@z\{Aa
,x.|*
`@z\{Bb
,x.|
`@z\{Cc
,x.|*
`@z\{Dd
,x.|
`@z\{Ee
,x.|*
`@z\{Ff
,x.|
`@z\{Gg
,x.|*
`@z\{H
S{*
```

The first byte of input is a 0-based index, the remainder is the string to process: `\x02abcde`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/chip#@68VxaVToVelx5XgUBVT7ZgI4tVoQXhOSWAehOOcjCzlkoIk5ZqKLOWWhiTlno4s5cEVXK31/z9XakVJUWJyiZVCtGIsAA)
In this TIO, a newline character is the index, which means an index of `0x0a` = 10.

[Test cases!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#TY9LC4JAEMfv8ymmECxLXXscgoqeVqcO3qJD67pbQqjkEmZ9d/MRtHOY4c9vXn9GJc5R8lRa7BYmOJ2ivj26emGcoJ9ZuQWXRX5@L2mlPkajVn6tGrFmKtoECtpyFblCQburivbgvY2ivAuQcommgIPrzXTQQcQPZDTlGEaodVj5rSbCO@9CEAOWkTzCSApsnzOtamvjB@04kXZlpk5W8kLz@XdYT3F2i8sNES8IoT4LOBDnVwcUWzP0gQx7pmEDGQ2dkTOefAE)
These use hex input + printf to make it clearer what's happening.

#### How does it work?

`S{*`

This suppresses output for all bytes, by default. If powered, this can be overridden. It is a not-gate based on an xor-gate (`{`).

`Aa`, `Bb`, `Cc`, etc.

These relay the input to the output for every byte, unless suppressed. Note that the `h` is missing, this is because we never need to output something with the high bit set.

```
,x.
`@z\{D
```

This is the real meat of it all. There are eight of these, one for each bit of the index (a one-byte index means that indexes are not able to be specified above 255). This reads in the index on the first cycle only with switches (`\`). The index bits have been flipped with an xor gate (`{`), which is almost negation. Then, for each character of the string, this value is incremented via some half-adders (`@`). When this value is incremented from `0xff` to `0x00`, it uses the carry from the high bit to unsuppress output for that character, meaning that it is printed.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 11 bytes

```ruby
->n,s{s[n]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#q7D9r2uXp1NcXRydF1v7n6ugtKRYoSLaQEc9MSk5JVU99j8A)

Comment: [`proc &:[]` is shorter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/121827/41042) :P

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth - 3 bytes

```
@wE
```

[Try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40wE&input=abcde%0A0&debug=0)

Answer (score 0):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 1 byte

```
ü
```

Just a builtin!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6///wnv///zvlJGb8NwIA)

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC 3, 17 bytes

Woo! String indexing!

```
DEF A S,N?S[N]END
```

Defines a command `A` to print the result. Uses 0-indexing. Call like `A "string",number`.

### No string functions, 29

Here's one that uses absolutely no string-specific built-ins.

```
DEF A S,N
COPY T$,S,N,1?T$END
```

`COPY` is a memory copy command, capable of copying data between two compatible types. It's usually used for arrays, but it works on strings as well.

Answer (score 0):

## tcl, 18

```
string index $s $n
```

Input is on the variables `s` and `n`

Output is the return of the script

[demo](http://rextester.com/SAKZF53688) — Iterates a list with all test case pairs and outputs them to console.

Answer (score 0):

## x86 Machine Code, 13 bytes

```
8B 44 24 04 03 44 24 08 8A 08 8A C1 C3
```

Which disassembles to:

```
  00000000: 8B 44 24 04        mov         eax,dword ptr [esp+4]
  00000004: 03 44 24 08        add         eax,dword ptr [esp+8]
  00000008: 8A 08              mov         cl,byte ptr [eax]
  0000000A: 8A C1              mov         al,cl
  0000000C: C3                 ret
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 13 bytes

```
=MID(B1,A1,1)
```

1-indexed `n` in A1.
Text in B1.

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 1 byte

Another built-in, 1-indexed:

```
!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X/H///@m/5WMDU0MTS2VAA)

Answer (score 0):

### Julia 0.6.0 (13 bytes)

`f(s,n)=(s[n])`

s is a string, n the index. Pretty simple since Julia considers strings as arrays so I just call the index in the array. Julia is a 1 indexing.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0/f8/TaNYJ0/TVqM4Oi9Wk@v/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically), <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```
$:7~(~*1-1/1)6@7
```

*(1-based index)*

Input format is `n abcde`, where `n` is the index, and `abcde` is the string.

How it works:

```
$:7              Get numeric input and set notepad to it
   ~             Skip next character (the space)
    (       )6   Do while the notepad is nonzero
     ~           Get next character of input
      *1-1/1     Subtract 1 from notepad (found by Kamil Drakari)
              @7 Output the current input character
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##Sy5NykxOzMmp/P8/yNjFMMhQxcq8TqNO10DTzMH8/38jhcSk5JRUAA)

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL, 29 bytes

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(s,n,1)FROM t
```

Input is taken via a pre-existing table **t** with integer **n** and string **s**, [per our IO standards](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341).

Answer (score 0):

Rebol, Red 4 bytes

```
s/:n
```

(need to make body at least 30 to satisfy submission nanny)

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPCG. You can use the HTML comment tag `<!-- ... -->` to fulfill your post length needs. Also, I would suggest using a `#` markdown or HTML header tag to start your post with a header.

Comment: Rather than adding markup comments, consider adding an explanation to your answer on how your program works. This will improve the quality of your answers and make it more likely that it will attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 1 byte

```
§
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///Q8v//jRXUE5OSU1LVAQ)

Finally a showcase for the implicit input! Works regardless of the order of the input (if the string or int comes first).

Answer (score 0):

## *[Acc!!](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!)*, 85 bytes

```python
N
Count i while _/128^i/32 {
_+128^(i+1)*N
}
Count j while N/48 {
_/128
}
Write _%128
```

Takes the string on one line of stdin and the 0-based index, in unary, on the following line. (I hope unary is okay. Decimal I/O is a pain in *Acc!!*) [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/9@Pyzm/NK9EIVOhPCMzJ1UhXt/QyCIuU9/YSKGaK14bxNHI1DbU1PLjqoUqzYIq9dM3sQApAukASoYXZZYA9asCef//Jyoo2iokcRkaAgA)

#### Commented

```python
# Read printable ASCII characters into the accumulator, storing the first character
# in the least significant place
N
Count i while _/128^i/32 {
_+128^(i+1)*N
}
# Read 1s, shifting the accumulator down by one character's worth each time
Count j while N/48 {
_/128
}
# We have now removed the first i characters from the original input string,
# which means the first remaining character is the one at index i (0-based)
Write _%128
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-plF`, 9 bytes

```perl
$_=$F[<>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lbFLdrGLvb//5DU4hIuY67EpOSU1DQuE67E4pS09AwuQ67C8tSikkouk3/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULctwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge-98 (FBBI)](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 5 bytes

1-indexing. Input is the index, a space and the string.

```
&k~,@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/Xy27Tsfh/38jhcSk5JRUAA)

This just reads *index* characters as input and prints the last one.